# FedEx Rating API is not working in Sandbox Postmen Environment. Erroring as "Operation Forbidden"

Tags: c#, .net, api, postman, fedex

I have created account with Postmen site at: https://secure.postmen.com/login
I got API Key.

I am referring to documentation at: https://docs.postmen.com/fedex.html#rates-calculate-rates/

Below is the JSON I am submitting and I am getting "**Operation Forbidden**" Error.
What am i missing? Do i need to pass any other params? Appreciate your responses.

In the Postman **Header**, I am specifying **content-type** as **application/json** and passing **postmen-api-key** as well.
Since I already created account, I got Shipper Account ID.

**This is the Rates URL:** https://secure.postmen.com/explorer/sandbox/v3/rates

I am testing everything in **POSTMAN**.

***JSON:***

```
    {
  "async": false,
  "shipper_accounts": [
    {
      "id": "My Account ID XXXX"
    }
  ],
  "is_document": false,
  "shipment": {
    "ship_from": {
      "contact_name": "Elmira Zulauf",
      "company_name": "Kemmer-Gerhold",
      "street1": "5800 Windward Pkwy",
          "city": "Alpharetta",
          "state": "GA",
          "postal_code": "30005",
      "country": "USA",
      "type": "business"
    },
    "ship_to": {
      "contact_name": "Dr. Moises Corwin",
      "phone": "1-140-225-6410",
      "email": "Giovanna42@yahoo.com",
      "street1": "1800 W Hillcrest Dr",
      "city": "Newbury Park",
      "postal_code": "91320",
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "USA",
      "type": "residential"
    },
    "parcels": [
      {
        "description": "Food XS",
        "box_type": "custom",
        "weight": {
          "value": 2,
          "unit": "kg"
        },
        "dimension": {
          "width": 20,
          "height": 40,
          "depth": 40,
          "unit": "cm"
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "description": "Food Bar",
            "origin_country": "USA",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": {
              "amount": 3,
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "weight": {
              "value": 0.6,
              "unit": "kg"
            },
            "sku": "imac2014"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks
Rita

Comment: Can you post what your request looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing via POSTMAN, according to https://docs.postmen.com/, full url for calculate rates should be like below,

Sandbox: https://sandbox-api.postmen.com/v3/rates
Production: https://production-api.postmen.com/v3/rates

sandbox can be used for testing